# Datatype of DTO Class

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, dto

What should be the datatype of properties in Data Transfer Object(DTO) Classes?
Ex: My Domain Class may be :

```
class Product { 
    string name; 
    decimal price;
    double quantity;
}
```

Can I create and use a generic DTO like this:

```
class ProductDTO {
    object name;
    object price;
    object quantity;
}
```

so that the DTO can be sent to different Datalayers for db mapping(oracle sql or any other db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this. What's the advantage?

The user of your DTO class has no idea about the types of the fields/properties. He can probably guess that the Name field should be string, but what about price and quantity? Are they doubles? Decimals? Integers?

Obviously he can put anything in there, and it will compile and run, but then you'll have to check the types in your datalayer and throw exceptions when types mismatch (and if you don't, your database probably will).

Perhaps you could use generics instead, something like

```
class ProductDTO<Nt, Pt, Qt>
{
    Nt name;
    Pt price;
    Qt quantity;
    public ProductDTO(Nt name, Pt price, Qt quantity)
    {
         this.name = name;
         this.price = price;
         this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var dto1 = new ProductDTO<string, decimal, double>("product1", 12.3m, 33.0); // name is string, price is decimal, quantity is double
var dto2 = new ProductDTO<string, double, int>("product2", 122.4, 15);  // string, double, int
```

You can also create a static method and class and let the type inferencing do the job:

```
static class ProductDTO
{
    public static ProductDTO<N, P, Q> Create<N, P, Q>(N name, P price, Q quantity)
    {
        return new ProductDTO<N, P, Q>(name, price, quantity);
    }
}
```

And then

```
var dto3 = ProductDTO.Create("product3", 123.4, 56.7);
```